# Sending information from Java to Java script?

Tags: java, javascript, netbeans, applet

I've been trying to send information from Java to Java script using the JSObject but i keep receiving a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.deploy.appcontext.AppContext exception i'm using netbeans 7.1.

Here is the full stack trace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/deploy/appcontext/AppContext
    at MapTest.MapApplet.init(MapApplet.java:23)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:434)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.deploy.appcontext.AppContext
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
   ... 3 more
```

It is referring to this line of code

```
    win = JSObject.getWindow(this);
```

These are all my imports

```
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;
import java.lang.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
```

I really need help with this can't seem to find solutions anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you testing your Applet? JSObject is not supported in Appletviewer.

Comment: I've only ran the program on netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar error and was able to solve it by adding `deploy.jar` found in the local Java install to the project build path. Not sure how to do this in netbeans but for others using maven you can try adding the folowing dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>sun</groupId>
    <artifactId>deploy</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/deploy.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```